# Wireless LAN not working on Lenovo Ideapad 330

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo Ideapad 330. After installation Wireless LAN adapter is not working.
Output of `lspci -knn | grep -i Net -A2`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
```

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/a/1074182/816190